# unnecessary watcher in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I create super simple angular app like the [following](http://jsbin.com/siyan/1)

```
<html ng-app>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>{{"hello"}}</body>
</html>
```

I found that the `$rootScope` has one `$watcher` for the expression `{{"hello"}}`, it would be nice that angularjs will be smart enough to find that the expression is a constant, so there is no need to watch it again. This feature (if supported) can be useful sometime such as `{{ "" | toRemdomNumber }}`, `{{ "key" | getResourceByKey }}`. This save some memory consumption and computation when scope is in digest.

Is this possible?

I know creating a directive such as bindonce is super simple as well, what I want is that angularjs core / $interpolate service should be smart enough the parse the expression, so that unncessary $watcher will not be created.

Comment: https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce <-- perhaps this is what you're looking for

Comment: http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/removing-the-unneeded-watches/#disqus_thread   great post on this topic

Comment: Using a directive like "bindonce" is a workaround. But the problem here is the {{expression}} syntax, which is no directive can solve. To me this is inefficiency of $interpolate service, I hope the angularjs team can make it smarter.

Comment: some translation directive like <div translate="key"></div> works more efficiently than <div>{{"key" | translate}} {{other interpolate}}</div>, however the latter is obvious flexible. Due to unnecessary watcher, the latter can not be used in large scale, because it is slow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Angular my self, but I found this directive called bindonce on github. https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce  It will show you how you can bind constants once. (It gets rid of their watchers after it first binds.) It even has support for filters, and it eliminates unnecessary watches.

Here is an example of bindonce used with a filter.

```
<div bindonce="Person">
    <span bo-bind="Person.bill | currency:'USD$'"></span>
</div>
```

Here's an article on how to unbind the watcher yourself if you want to try that.  I just skimmed over it so far.  Like I said I'm kind of new so I don't understand all of it. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2480-Unbinding-watch-Listeners-In-AngularJS.htm